# NetworkError: 404 while loading dojo.dom under iWidget environment @IBMBusinessSpace

Tags: dojo, websphere

im starting to dig DOJO which is used in my current environment: iWidget @ IBM Business Space 
so i faced the problem with dojo.require("dojo.dom")
all other modules required earlier in the code loaded fine

Browser Console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 ProxyServlet%3A+%2F...edojo%2Fdojo%2Fdom%2Ejs -    http://127.0.0.1:39191/mum/js/bluedojo/dojo/dom.js"
com.ibm.mm.iwidget.widget.IWidgetWrapperExtendedImpl IWidgetWrapper._handleEventInternal: widget: testWidget, eventName: onedit, HandleEventException: Error: Could not load 'dojo.dom'; last tried './dom.js'
```

Request Headers

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie  _testWidget_myTreeSaveStateCookie=treedata; JSESSIONID=4x5yqx2lqocv
Host    127.0.0.1:39191
Referer http://127.0.0.1:39191/mum/testWidget.jsp?iWidget=http://localhost:9081/FileClient/FileClientWidget.xml
```

Response

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><pre>ProxyServlet: /mum/js/bluedojo/dojo/dom.js</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/mum/js/bluedojo/dojo/dom.js</p>
```

p.s. example i was unsuccesfully trying to execute under iWidget environment worked fine on the simple html page in my another Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Comment: looks like a pretty straightforward 404, which version of dojo are you using? A quick check tells me that dojo/dom was only introduced in 1.7

Comment: im using 1.8.3, but it seems ibm iWidget runtime under Business Space uses its own version. if so I donno what to do

Comment: I have 1.8.3 in my Eclipce IDE and ooops! 1.4.3_IBM (21629) in IBM universal test client for iWidget and Business Space runtime respectively. So what am i gonna do now?